# Encoding Json response data using jQuery

Tags: json, html, jquery

i am fetching json data using jQuery Ajax and displaying as HTML.
The problem what i got is the response data is not encoded it is coming with special characters..like...`â€œflanking` 
how to get rid of this characters...the code what i wrote is

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "data.js",
dataType: "json",
ContentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-32",
success: function(data) {
   $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
   //var bioData = data.bio.replace(/™/, "");
   var div_data ="<div class='fixed'><div class='left' style='background-image:url("+data.image+")'></div><div class='right'><div class='box'>"+data.name+""+data.title+""+bioData+"</div></div></div>";
   $(div_data).appendTo("#imgs");
 });
 });
```

my data.js

```
 {
"posts": [
    {
        "name": "<h1>Philippe Capart</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>GM Rheumatology, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Philippe_Capart.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Philippe joined Abbott in 2012 as Director, Rheumatoid Arthritis, Global Marketing. Strong of 13 years in the pharmaceutical industry, he built his experience  in different roles such as sales, marketing and business development, including a Regional Commercial role for Latin America. Philippe earned a Masterâ€™s Degree of Science in Cellular and Molecular Biology and Physiology, with a specialization in Molecular and Cellular Genetics and a Diploma of Higher Specialized Studies in Business Management in the Healthcare Sector.  Convinced of the high potential for HUMIRA in Rheumatology over the next 10 years, Philippe is looking forward to engaged discussion during the Forum.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Nicole Selenko-Gebauer</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Rheumatology Therapeutic Area Lead, Global Medical Affairs</h2>",
        "image": "images/Nicole_Selenko_Gebauer.JPG",
        "bio": "<p>Nicole heads the Global Medical Affairs group in Rheumatology US and ex-US.  She leads the overall strategy and oversees the tactical contributions of the GMA team in Rheumatology.  Nicole believes in a proactive â€œflanking partnershipâ€ making Medical Affairs a critical stakeholder for brand strategy globally as well as on the affiliate level.  She closely interacts with Philippe Capart (GM Rheumatology) to assure that Medical and Commercial are fully complementary and aligned.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Antonio Della Croce</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>SpA Director, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Antonio_Andion.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Antonio joined the Global team in February.  He spent the last 6 years in the Italian Immunology Team, navigating across all Humira indications, and the last 3 years as Rheumatology BUM and BTL.  After many Forums seated among the audience, Antonio is excited in welcoming you all to join the Global Team in this unique event! </p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Ikechi Ogbonna</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Rheumatology Brand Management Coordination Lead</h2>",
        "image": "images/Ikechi_Ogbonna.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Ikechi joined AbbVie this past May, coming from Pfizer HQ in New York, and brings a rich experience from US Sales, US Managed Markets, International Government Affairs, and International Strategic Planning & Operations.  In his current role, he is responsible for successfully implementing the cross functional brand management for HUMIRA in Rheumatology by driving key deliverables such as the 5-year Strategic Brand Plan and rollout of Fosbury across the various functions.  Ikechi is looking forward to experiencing his first Humira Forum and connecting with new colleagues!</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Christopher Marks</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Director, Cross Indication Strategies, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Christopher_Marks.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Chris was already a familiar face within Abbvie when he joined Global Marketing 15 months ago as he had been involved in many projects and assignments on HUMIRA whilst he was at the MSI Consultancy. In fact, this is his 4th Forum! Chris leads the Cross Indication team with responsibility for those aspects of marketing that impact all indications including branding, enhancements, benefit risk and Forum! Chris knows the remarkable impact that HUMIRA has on patientsâ€™ lives - his daughter has Crohnâ€™s, but has been in drug-free remission for over 3 years after treatment with HUMIRA.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Matt Kowal</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Director, Business Intelligence, Immunology, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Matt_Kowal.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Matt joined AbbVie one year ago â€“ finally deciding to come over to the client side after a successful career as a commercial strategy consultant.  He most recently was a Partner at bioStrategies Group in Chicago where he focused exclusively on the biopharma industry.  Today, Matt leads the Global Business Intelligence team for Humira across all indications and works closely with Global, Area and Affiliate brand teams to help make a remarkable impact on patientsâ€™ lives.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Keith Fournier</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Global Regulatory Lead for RA and JIA</h2>",
        "image": "images/Keith_Fournier.JPG",
        "bio": "<p>Keith joined AbbVie in February 2013 and the RA team in June.  In his role as Global Regulatory Lead he chairs the Global Regulatory Project Team â€“ which is responsible for providing the regulatory strategy and functional plan in support of the brand.  This is Keithâ€™s first Forum and he isnâ€™t quite sure what heâ€™s gotten himself into.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Bao Hoang, Director</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Immunology, Global Market Access</h2>",
        "image": "images/Hoang_Bao.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Bao joined Abbott/AbbVie in 2006 as a Clinical Executive supporting all marketed products in the US.  Two years ago, he joined the global team in pricing, reimbursement, and market access, with responsibility for the immunology portfolio.  Prior to joining AbbVie, Bao practiced as a pharmacist and worked as an ex-payer.  This is Baoâ€™s third Forum and he looks forward to another impactful year with HUMIRA.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Aileen Pangan</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Project Director, Immunology Clinical Development</h2>",
        "image": "images/Aileen_Pangan.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Aileen Pangan is a board-certified rheumatologist who joined the Humira team in 2004 from a university-based academic practice.  She was previously the Rheumatology lead for Medical Affairs, but over the past 5 years  has been the senior medical director for the SpA clinical development team.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Antonio Andion</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>SpA Senior Product Manager, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Antonio_Andion.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Antonio joined the Global Team in 2012.  He has a mixed experience with Pharma and Consumer companies where he focused in Direct to Consumer communications.  He leads efforts related to Patient Initiatives like Donâ€™t Turn Your Back On It; T2T Connect; Adherence.  Latin America is his assigned region.  He is looking forward to build with you new possibilities for SpA patients!</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Julie Brown</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Senior Manager Business Intelligence, Humira RA</h2>",
        "image": "images/Julie_Brown.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Julie joined the Humira team in April 2013 after working for a major pharmaceutical competitor on their Immunology products Gastroenterology and Dermatology indications. In her new role, she leads the Rheumatoid Arthritis Market Research for Humira. This is Julieâ€™s first Forum and she is looking forward to networking with her global affiliates and learning how we can work together in new innovative ways.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Anabela Cardoso</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Medical Director, Global Medical Affairs</h2>",
        "image": "images/Anabela_Cardoso.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Anabela, a Rheumatologist with clinical and research experience, joined the Global Medical Affairs team one year ago. Anabelaâ€™s prior roles included Medical Director in Portugal and in Europe Southâ€“WEC, where she drove for the implementation of FutureFit medical and multi-country Humira studies. In her current role, Anabela leads the medical affairs research in RA franchise and medical education in JIA. This is Anabelaâ€™s 4th Forum, and sheâ€™s looking forward to another great meeting with fruitful exchanges, learning and fun!</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Alexander Peter Dorr</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Associate Scientific Director, Global Medical Affairs Immunology</h2>",
        "image": "images/Alexander_Dirr.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Alex has been a member of the Global Medical Affairs team at AbbVie since October 2013. His main focus is on SpA.  He has been responsible for the disease background and ABILITY-1 efficacy slides prepared for the HUMIRA in nr-axSpA FDA Advisory Committee in July 2013. At that time, the team had created a total of 2,000 slides.  This is Alexâ€™s second Forum.  He is passionate about HUMIRA, the global and affiliate team members and is a strong believer in the new AbbVie culture.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Roland Eastmond</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>RA Senior Product Manager, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Roland_Eastmond.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Roland joined the Global team one year ago, after spending the last 12 years at the Canadian affiliate where his most recent position was a District Sales Manager for the Humira RA team.  He has also been a part of the Humira franchise for the last 10 years where in addition to District Sales Manager, he held positions in Business Intelligence & Senior Product Manager for RA & SpA. In his Global role, he leads efforts related to the WEC area; the HCP messaging, CLM, TUI & the Overarching Brand strategy.  Roland is looking forward to sharing the Global 2014 Vision & answering any questions from of his International colleagues!</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Stefan Florentinus</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Associate Scientific Director, Global Medical Affairs</h2>",
        "image": "images/Stefan_Florentinus.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Stefan joined the medical affairs team in 2011, after spending a year working on OPTIMA in the global marketing team.  Previous to joining the global team, he worked as a medical advisor in the Dutch affiliate.  In his current role, Stefan leads the medical education part of the RA franchise.  This is Stefanâ€™s 5th Forum and thatâ€™s why heâ€™s looking so forward to it!</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Antonin Folliasson</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Area Commercial Manager, Rheumatology, EEMEA</h2>",
        "image": "images/Antonin_Folliasson.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Antonin joined Abbott France in 2009 as Rheumatology (SpA) Group Product Manager, HUMIRA, followed by a short term assignment with the Global Marketing Team also on SpA, where he focused in particular on competition and drove the 1st Global Axial SpA Scientific Event (Barcelona).  In his current Area role, heâ€™s really enjoying being part of a real team in an exciting environment, and he leads efforts to strengthen synergies and positive impact between affiliate teams and the markets.  Heâ€™s passionately looking forward to another incredible week with the entire team!</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Arijit Ganguli</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Associate Director, US-lead Rheumatology, Health Economics & Outcomes Research</h2>",
        "image": "images/Arijit_Ganguli.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Arijit joined the HUMIRA HEOR team in December 2011, but has been with AbbVie since 2009. He is responsible for all HEOR efforts related to Rheumatoid Arthritis and Juvenile Idiopathic Arthritis indications of HUMIRA.  Last yearâ€™s Forum was Arijitâ€™s maiden Forum and he is very excited to experience it again. Arijit welcomes everyone to join him to relive it along with him.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Fabrice Gillas</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Associate Medical Director, GMA cross TA</h2>",
        "image": "images/Fabrice_Gillas.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Fabrice joined Global Medical Affairs one year ago after two years spent as Associate Director within the Global Marketing team.  During these last 3 years, he has developed a real expertise in medication adherence; he recently joined the cross TA GMA team to lead all Adherence research projects. This Forum in San Diego will be his 7th Forum and this is always for him a great moment to share with colleagues from all around the world!</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Pamela Graves-Moore</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Director, Global Strategic Health Initiatives</h2>",
        "image": "images/Pamela_Graves_Moore.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>With more than two decades of experience in the industry, including lengthy stints in the highly charged political environments of Washington, DC, and Brussels, Pamela came to Abbott in 2006 to help to promote Western Europe & Canada government affairs.  There, in Paris, she ultimately conceived, developed and led the implementation of more broadly based Strategic Health Initiatives (SHIs), which, since 2012, are a growing global approach to propel the companyâ€™s most important therapeutic areas.  SHIs aim to strengthen standards of care through multi-stakeholder platforms that effect positive change in clinical and public policy.  Now based in Chicago, Pamela collaborates with Global, Area and Affiliate colleagues in advancing a rich panoply of SHIs, including Fit for Work and Good to Grow, as well as platforms for Parkinsonâ€™s and HCV.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Donna Gray</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Director Patient Adherence, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Donna_Gray.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Donna joined the Global Patient Adherence team in 2012.  She started her career at AbbVie in 1999 with the US Renal Care Team and has held a variety of roles in sales and marketing.  Donna is a Registered Nurse and spent the first half of her career caring for individuals with chronic diseases.  In her current role, Donna has worked with cross functional teams across all of AbbVieâ€™s brands to develop and launch Patient Journeys globally.  She is excited about the progress made this year to better understand the needs of the patient and our journey toward development of a unique Patient Experience with our brand in 2014 and beyond!</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Maja Hojnik</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Associate Medical Director, GMA Rheumatology</h2>",
        "image": "images/Maja_Hojnik.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Maja joined the GMA Rheumatology Team a little less than a year ago, after spending 8 previous years in different positions in the company: Slovene Affiliate Medical Director; Associate Medical Director with International Medical Affairs; and most recently within Regional Medical Affairs supporting Humira in our former CEE Region. In GMA, Maja is dedicated to spondyloarthritis (SpA) and primarily responsible for research in this therapeutic area. This is Majaâ€™s 6th Humira Forum, but for the first time in a presenter role.  Thatâ€™s why she is especially looking forward to meeting and discussing with colleagues all around the World.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Tim Jantsch</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Director, Marketing & Sales Force Excellence</h2>",
        "image": "images/Timothy_Jantsch.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Tim joined the Global team 18 months ago after spending 22 years with another major pharmaceutical manufacturer in various U.S. and Global roles. In this new Global role at AbbVie, he leads efforts to partner with Global, Area and Affiliate cross-functional commercial teams to define processes and standards to support Marketing and Sales Force Excellence that creates the â€œAbbVieâ€ way. His is looking forward to networking with colleagues from around the world and defining new ways of working!</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Josh Sang Hyun Lee</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>SpA Senior Product Manager, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Josh_Lee.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Josh recently joined the SpA Global team in July after spending the last 5 years in AbbVie as Gastroenterology Commercial Manager on the Latin America Area team, and Dermatology Product Manager in Global Marketing.  In his current role, he leads efforts related to the JAPAC area; the HCP messaging, CLM, CoRe, and the overarching brand strategy.  This is Joshâ€™s 4th Forum and he is so much looking forward to meeting old and new friends from around the world</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Luis Alfonso Martin</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>RA Product Manager, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Luis_Martin.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Luis joined the Global RA team 2 years ago after roles in the Spanish affiliate, global business intelligence and commercial management in Latin America, this area being the one he currently covers for the RA Global Team.  Luis has been championing the T2T Connect program, internal communication and the competitive knowledge platform CoRe.  His primary focus and area of excitement for 2014 is working towards patients as a stakeholder.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>David Murphy</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>SpA Senior Product Manager, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/David_Murphy.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>David joined the global marketing team just over 2 years ago after stints in the UK in RA marketing, Regional management and training teams.  He now focuses on multi stakeholder initiatives including disease knowledge and payers.  He is looking forward to this yearâ€™s forum and continuing the work to build SpA expertise.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Kelli Teno</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Senior Manager, Global Public Affairs</h2>",
        "image": "images/Kelli_Teno.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Kelli joined the AbbVie global communications group in August, after spending 10 years supporting blue chip pharmaceutical companies in the agency role.  She now leads global public affairs efforts for Humira RA, specifically the RA: Join the Fight campaign.  She is thrilled to be a part of such a strong initiative and is looking forward to working together to ensure RA Join the Fight has a remarkable impact on patients across the globe.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Anna Tsouluhas</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Senior Strategic Lead, Cross Indication Strategies</h2>",
        "image": "images/Anna_Tsouluhas.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>A Humira veteran, Anna joined the Global team in April of 2011 after spending 14 years with the Canadian affiliate where she launched HUMIRA in several indications and was the business unit manager for rheumatology. In her current role, Anna leads efforts to manage some of the key challenges facing HUMIRA and to find new growth opportunities that are common across all therapeutic areas. This is Annaâ€™s 10th Forum, having only missed 2 due to launch her other 2 babies</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Chris White</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>SpA Senior Product Manager, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Chris_White.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>It has been thirteen years since I joined AbbVie in Canada and eight on Humira. In that time, I worked on the launches of PsA and Psoriasis, lead a marketing team in IBD and then spent the past three years as a Sales Manager in Dermatology. Since June, I have been on the Global Marketing team and lead efforts in the EEMEA area while also focusing my global responsibilities on Fosbury/ Messaging and Differentiation in AS and ax-SpA, MRI training and keeping an on eye on the external environment. I look forward to re-connecting with all of you in San Diego.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Malte Wolff</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>Senior Manager Global Market Access, Pricing, and Reimbursement</h2>",
        "image": "images/Malte_Wolff.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Malte joined the global market access team in September after working for the German affiliate for the past 4 years. In Germany, he led the local HEOR team with focus on Rheumatology and supervised Health technology assessment projects. In his new global role, he is responsible for all Rheumatoid Arthritis related projects and strategies within Market Access. As this is Malteâ€™s first Forum visit in his new role, he is excited to meet all new colleagues across all areas.</p>"
    },
    {
        "name": "<h1>Chip Conley</h1>",
        "title": "<h2>RA Senior Product Manager, Global Marketing</h2>",
        "image": "images/Chip_Conley.jpg",
        "bio": "<p>Chip joined the Global team a few months ago, after spending 2Â½ years as a SpA Product Manager on the US team, where he focused in particular on digital projects.  In his new Global role, he leads efforts related to the JAPAC area; the Treat-to-Target program; as well as Payer issues.  This is Chipâ€™s first Forum, and heâ€™s looking forward to meeting and learning from colleagues around the world!</p>"
    }
]
}
```

pls help me...

Comment: Can you write what actually got in "data" variable.?

Comment: when i say alert(data)..it says [object Object]

Comment: @Maulikpatel: i edited my questn...added data.js file..pls check it

Comment: Why don't you try removing this line and see.. `ContentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-32",`

Comment: @DeepakMishra Mishra:nothing will happen if i remove that line...

Comment: @kisna set the content type of the server response as `application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @DeepakMishra:i checked using UTF-8,UTF-16,UTF-32...still the same

Comment: @kisna do you already have those characters in the source file?

Comment: @DeepakMishra: yup..i have those splchars in data.js file...

Comment: @kisna so why you cannot modify those special characters or even remove them in the source file itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

(ive changed a bit the display for you to be able to see )

http://jsbin.com/IcapedIw/15/edit

```
   $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){

   var div_data ="<div class='fixed'><div class='left' style='background-image:url("+data.image+")'></div><div class='right'><div class='box'>"+data.name+""+data.bio.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/g, "")+""+1+"</div></div></div>";
   $(div_data).appendTo("#imgs");
 });
```

it's a known problem : ([**see here**](http://markmcb.com/2011/11/07/replacing-ae%E2%80%9C-ae%E2%84%A2-aeoe-etc-with-utf-8-characters-in-ruby-on-rails/))

```
String.prototype.cleanup = function() {

   return this.replace(/â€¦/g, '…')
              .replace(/â€“/g, '–')
              .replace(/â€™/g, '’')
              .replace(/â€œ/g, '“')
              .replace(/â€/g, '”');
}
```

Comment: its appending p in starting and p1 in ending to the data...other than tis its working fine..

Comment: You have any idea how append full stop '.' at the end of every data

Comment: what do you mean  full stop '.'

Comment: and one more thing is missing...the single quote is not coming...masters would be like master's...but the songle quote is not coming..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44319/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-kisna)

Comment: "it's a known problem", please post a link describing or a description of the known problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ajax call is expectng a json response. I would suggest using `getJson`

```
$.getJSON( "data.js", function( data ) {
     ....
});
```

Also make sure the content-type is properly set at UTF-8 in the response header.

```
application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: where should i write the content-type?

Comment: for php `header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');` and for java `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");` before you write the response.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "data.js",
  dataType: "json",
  ContentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-32",
  success: function(data) {
  $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
      var decoded = $("<div/>").html(data.title).text();
      //var bioData = data.bio.replace(/™/, "");
      var div_data ="<div class='fixed'>"+ decoded+"</div>";
      $(div_data).appendTo("#imgs");
  });
});
```

**or use htmlEncode**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "data.js",
   dataType: "json",
   ContentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-32",
   success: function(data) {
   $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
      var div_data ="<div class='fixed'>"+ htmlEncode(data.title)+"</div>";
       $(div_data).appendTo("#imgs");
   });
});
```

Comment: the data is not displaying...its empty